# Import CSV to mysql database with a cell containing multiple values separated with commas

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import

I have a csv file with 2 cells ProductId and Product Images. Here the Id would be unique but Product Image cell can have more than one image url separated by commas like image1.jpg,image2,jpg etc.

Here when I am trying to import this file into mysql database then only image1.jpg is being added in the ProductImage field of database table and the next image url i.e image2.jpg is being added onto id column of the next entry.

Please suggest how can I solve this by having all image urls on a same column in database table.

Comment: Wrap the disaster/nightmare column in quotation marks

Comment: I suppose you want a row for each `ProductId`->`Product Image` so that you have a lookup table? This should be fairly easy to script. Otherwise, as @Strawberry suggests, add quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Surround 2.nd column with ""
.